# Can't Access API Umbrella's Homepage

Tags: api, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I installed [API Umbrella](https://github.com/NREL/api-umbrella) on Ubuntu 14.04 server according to [Getting Started](https://api-umbrella.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) guide.
After I modified /etc/api-umbrella/api-umbrella.yml and start api-umbrella server, I can't access it's homepage in the browser.

I've checked the firewall of the server. Port 80 and 443 are all open for incoming request.

When access with `curl umbrella.my.website`, where "umbrella.my.website" is the server running api-umbrella service, I got the following result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The requested URL was not found on this server."
  }
}
```

How can I get the homepage like the image below

> Browse to your server’s hostname. You should land on the default homepage:

in the document?

The config file "/etc/api-umbrella/api-umbrella.yml" on the server:

```
# services:
#   - general_db
#   - log_db
#   - router
#   - web
web:
  admin:
    initial_superusers:
      - leo@newfairs.com
#     auth_strategies:
#       enabled:
#         - github
#         - google
#         - persona
#       github:
#         client_id:
#         client_secret:
#       google:
#         client_id:
#         client_secret:
# elasticsearch:
#   hosts:
#     - http://127.0.0.1:14002
# mongodb:
#   url: mongodb://127.0.0.1:14001/api_umbrella
# nginx:
#   workers: 4
# gatekeeper:
#   workers: 4
```

It's verified that port 80 is being used by api-umbrella server by stopping and starting it:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/api-umbrella stop
 * Stopping API Umbrella api-umbrella
   ...done.
$ sudo netstat -lnput|grep :80
$ sudo /etc/init.d/api-umbrella start
 * Starting API Umbrella api-umbrella
   ...done.
$ sudo netstat -lnput|grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17077/router.conf
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      17077/router.conf
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide the file you modified (/etc/api-umbrella/api-umbrella.yml).

Comment: check who is using your ports. Apache may already be started and using them. You can also try to change the ports and see if it works (https://api-umbrella.readthedocs.org/en/latest/server/listen-ports.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not alone - https://github.com/NREL/api-umbrella/issues/263 Others have experienced similar issues on based on different operating systems.

1. Check whether you are giving the right host name. Localhost may not work. Deploy somewhere that has a proper host name.
2. I recommend you using the Docker version. It is simple and straight-forward. It worked almost out-of-the-box.